# How to find first non zero value in a column?

Tags: excel

in column A first value is 0, second is 0, third is 17, fourth is 0 and fifth is 32

[image: calculating first non zero value in a column]

in this case , first non zero value is 17. how to calculate it by formula

Comment: calculate what? are you looking to return the value 17?

Comment: yes in B1. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In cell B1:

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:A5<>0,),0))
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works, I've seen it everywhere but no explanations

Comment: Here the inner INDEX - INDEX(A1:A5<>0,) - returns a list of TRUEs and FALSEs depending on whether or not each value in A1:A5 is nonzero. So A1 would be FALSE, A2 would be FALSE, and A3, 4 and A5 would be TRUE. MATCH searches - MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(A1:A5<>0,),0) - for the first instance at which the INDEX list returns a TRUE (and therefore matches TRUE). Therefore, MATCH would return "3", as it searches from A1 to A5. Then, INDEX returns the third instance in A1:A5, which would be 17.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for the above formula:

The inner Index function evaluates the values in the A1:A5 range to either TRUE or FALSE based on the specified condition, that is, not equal to 0. So 17 and 32 evaluate to TRUE, everything else to FALSE. The Match function returns the row number where the first instance of the specified condition TRUE is. This occurs on the 3rd row of the range, so Match evaluates to 3. Finally, the outer Index functions returns the value at row number 3 in the specified A1:A5 range, which is 17.

Comment: Is your formula missing? I can see your explanation of your formula but not the formula itself.

Comment: @Michelle I think that's an explanation to the accepted answer. Since OP can't give a comment.